Cannot connect to K8s Kafka cluster from outside of cluster using VIP
I deploy Kafka helm chart https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/kafka/28.3.0 into my k8s cluster with 3 nodes. I also setup an VIP (10.255.251.9) using keepalived.
To allow external system to connect to the Kafka cluster, I set the loadBalancerIps to the VIP
externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  autoDiscovery:
    enabled: false
  controller:
    service:
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        external: 9095
      loadBalancerIPs:
        - 10.255.251.9
        - 10.255.251.9
        - 10.255.251.9
  broker:
    service:
      type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
      external: 9095
    loadBalancerIPs:
      - 10.255.251.9
      - 10.255.251.9
      - 10.255.251.9

List of kafka pods
Name                 Ready   Status
kafka-controller-0   1/1     Running  
kafka-controller-1   1/1     Running  
kafka-controller-2   1/1     Running  

List of kafka services

When I try to connect from outside of k8s cluster, I can connect through nodeIP:9095 but NOT VIP:9095.
I log into all the kafka pod the check the server.config.
listeners=CLIENT://:9092,INTERNAL://:9094,EXTERNAL://:9095,CONTROLLER://:9093
advertised.listeners=CLIENT://kafka-controller-2.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092,INTERNAL://kafka-controller-2.kafka-controller-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9094,EXTERNAL://10.255.251.9:9095
listener.security.protocol.map=CLIENT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT

Networkpolicy

Name:         kafka
Namespace:    default
Created on:   2024-11-28 07:47:48 +0000 UTC
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/instance=kafka
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
              app.kubernetes.io/name=kafka
              app.kubernetes.io/version=3.7.0
              helm.sh/chart=kafka-28.3.0
              release=kafka
              service=kafka
Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: kafka
              meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
Spec:
  PodSelector:     app.kubernetes.io/instance=kafka,app.kubernetes.io/name=kafka
  Allowing ingress traffic:
    To Port: 9092/TCP
    To Port: 9094/TCP
    To Port: 9093/TCP
    To Port: 9095/TCP
    From: <any> (traffic not restricted by source)
  Allowing egress traffic:
    To Port: <any> (traffic allowed to all ports)
    To: <any> (traffic not restricted by destination)
  Policy Types: Ingress, Egress

Please help!
Here is my full config.
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/kafka
  tag: 3.7.0-debian-12-r6
  debug: true
containerSecurityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
commonLabels:
  service: kafka
  release: kafka
listeners:
  client:
    containerPort: 9092
    protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    name: CLIENT
    sslClientAuth: none
  controller:
    name: CONTROLLER
    containerPort: 9093
    protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    sslClientAuth: none
  interbroker:
    containerPort: 9094
    protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    name: INTERNAL
    sslClientAuth: none
  external:
    containerPort: 9095
    protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
    name: EXTERNAL
    sslClientAuth: none
sasl:
  enabledMechanisms: PLAIN,SCRAM-SHA-256,SCRAM-SHA-512
  interBrokerMechanism: PLAIN
  controllerMechanism: PLAIN
  interbroker:
    user: inter_broker_user
  controller:
    user: controller_user
  client:
    users:
      - user
  existingSecret: kafka-credentials
kraft:
  enabled: true
allowPlaintextListener: false
controller:
  replicaCount: 3

externalAccess:
  enabled: true
  autoDiscovery:
    enabled: false
  controller:
    service:
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        external: 9095
      loadBalancerIPs:
        - 10.255.251.9
        - 10.255.251.9
        - 10.255.251.9
  broker:
    service:
      type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
      external: 9095
    loadBalancerIPs:
      - 10.255.251.9
      - 10.255.251.9
      - 10.255.251.9
networkPolicy:
  enable: true
  allowExternal: true
  allowExternalEgress: true
serviceAccount:
  create: true
rbac:
  create: true
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
persistence:
  enabled: true
  size: 10Gi
  annotations:
    helm.sh/resource-policy: keep


What is the error that you get when trying to connect at the external IP? I am not sure, but I was under the impression that each broker and the bootstrap server need to have their own IP addresses, otherwise how can the app be redirected on the correct kafka node which is the leader for the requested topic+partition? I don't have experience with bitnami kafka, but we use strimzi kafka and we expose externally with 4 load-balanced IP addresses.
